# Registry key values reverted to default after reboot in windows 2019

Tags: windows, windows-registry

To enable the admin share, I need to modify the `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` value to 1, so I set

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System Value: LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy = 1
```

But when I rebooted the machine, the value is reverted back to `0`. In Windows 2012 and 2016 I didn't face any prolem, but for Windows 2019 I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To help prevent a value changing, in *Regedit*:

- First, export the key, or better, back up the Registry lest something go amiss.
- Change the value of *LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy* to 1, as desired.
- Then, Right-click on the *key* containing the value.
- Click on *Permissions*.
- Click the *Advanced* button.
- Change *Owner* to yourself.
- Remove *Full Control* from other users than yourself, *wherever possible*.
- If this is not sufficient to "lock" the value after reboot, then repeat as above and finally change *Owner* to *NT Service\TrustedInstaller*.

*Caveat:* It is possible that some Windows process might *still* change the value, or might fail to work properly. In that case, there's a workaround:

- Right-click the key and *Export* it with the correct value for *LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy*.
- After each reboot, run the script to restore the value.

Comment: The author should verify they don't inverently have a group policy enabled that is restoring the value.  Windows will be unhappy if it's unable to change a registry key.